# How to set retention period in AWS S3

Tags: amazon-s3, curl, set, period, retention

I am trying to set retention period in S3 storage, in a shell script:

```
curl -k -X PUT $ENDPOINT -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -H "Accept: application/xml" -d "<Request><Login>${ACCESS_KEY_ID}</Login><Password>${SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}</Password></Request><ObjectLockConfiguration><ObjectLockEnabled>Enabled</ObjectLockEnabled><Rule><DefaultRetention><Mode>COMPLIANCE</Mode><Years>${RETYEARS}</Years></DefaultRetention></Rule></ObjectLockConfiguration>"
```

Nothing is returned to stdout. But this is returned to stderr:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   285    0     0  100   285      0  33348 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 35625
```

Does that mean it is working ( despite the stderr ) ?

Another line in the script ( and another ENDPOINT and other login and password ):

```
curl -k -X PUT $ENDPOINT -H "Date: `date`" -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -H "Accept: application/xml" -H "Authorization: ${ACCESS_KEY_ID}:${SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}" -d "<ObjectLockConfiguration><ObjectLockEnabled>Enabled</ObjectLockEnabled><Rule><DefaultRetention><Mode>COMPLIANCE</Mode><Years>${RETYEARS}</Years></DefaultRetention></Rule></ObjectLockConfiguration>"
```

Stdout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>MethodNotAllowed</Code>
<Message>The specified method is not allowed against this resource.</Message>
<Resource>/</Resource><RequestId>1669626042508238</RequestId></Error>
```

Stderr:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   407  100   221  100   186    488    410 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   487
```

This makes me a little confused. I would appreciate an answer.

I had hoped for returns confirming a positive result about the retention periods.

Regards

Anders

Comment: Are there some editing tricks required here? Stackoverflow shredded some lines in my post, especially the curl commands. I try to post them again:

Comment: curl -k -X PUT $ENDPOINT -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -H "Accept: application/xml" -d "<Request><Login>${ACCESS_KEY_ID}</Login><Password>${SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}</Password></Request><ObjectLockConfiguration><ObjectLockEnabled>Enabled</ObjectLockEnabled><Rule><DefaultRetention><Mode>COMPLIANCE</Mode><Years>${RETYEARS}</Years></DefaultRetention></Rule></ObjectLockConfiguration>"

Comment: curl -k -X PUT $ENDPOINT -H "Date: `date`" -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -H "Accept: application/xml" -H "Authorization: ${ACCESS_KEY_ID}:${SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}" -d "<ObjectLockConfiguration><ObjectLockEnabled>Enabled</ObjectLockEnabled><Rule><DefaultRetention><Mode>COMPLIANCE</Mode><Years>${RETYEARS}</Years></DefaultRetention></Rule></ObjectLockConfiguration>"

Comment: It's doubtful that command is working, the string you're sending isn't valid XML, and not properly signed, further the AWS Secret is a secret, and should never leave your machine.  Is there some reason you're not using an AWS SDK call?  It will handle these issues for you.

Comment: I changed the string to correct XML but I still get the same kind of output returned. What should the output look like if it is working? I am not using AWS SDK because I don't have access to it. Regarding signing, I did not know anything about it before reading your answer. Is it a must?

Comment: Yes, signing is required.  I'd add `-D -` to your command to show the error that S3 is likely returning.  PutObjectLockConfiguration does not return a body, it's a header only response.

Comment: I added "-D -" to my two curl-commans and this was returned, respectively:

Comment: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; object-src 'self'; frame-ancestors 'self';
X-Download-Options: noopen
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Pragma: no-cache
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-DNS-Prefetch-Control: off
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Length: 0

Comment: HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Date: Tue, 29 Nov 2022 18:15:34 GMT
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Length: 221
Connection: keep-alive
Server: StorageGRID/11.6.0.5
x-amz-request-id: 1669625739558567
x-amz-id-2: 12546953
x-ntap-sg-trace-id: 1255131a482bcb07

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>MethodNotAllowed</Code><Message>The specified method is not allowed against this resource.</Message><Resource>/</Resource><RequestId>1669625739558567</RequestId></Error>

Comment: But I will add a signature hash, etc, to my curl script and see what happens.

Comment: See my comments down below.

Answer (score 0):

Your Error:

> MethodNotAllowed  The specified method is not allowed against this
> resource.

I would assume this means your PUT method is not valid.  Try GET.
"Method" could mean something else.  I am not familiar with S3.  I'm just guessing.

Another thing I noticed about using curl is all the requests I fond on various site is they use a Signature hash. 
Example: [How to upload files on AWS S3 by using curl](https://www.gyanblog.com/aws/how-upload-aws-s3-curl/#curl-the-savior)

---

---

I could not find any documentation on using curl.  I did find this

> Define the Object Lock feature configuration parameters by specifying
> the retention mode and retention period for the new S3 bucket. The
> following example enables Governance retention mode for 90 days.
> Governance mode ensures that users cannot overwrite or delete an S3
> object version or alter its lock settings unless they have special
> permissions (e.g. root account access). Governance mode enables you to
> protect objects against deletion by most users while still allowing
> you to grant some users permission to alter the retention settings or
> delete the object if required.
> **Save these configuration parameters to
> a JSON file named object-lock-config.json**:

```
{
  "ObjectLockEnabled": "Enabled",
  "Rule": {
    "DefaultRetention": {
      "Mode": "GOVERNANCE",
      "Days": 90
    }
  }
}
```

---

---

You have an XML error.
I am not saying it will work after fixing this error.
But it definitely  will not work with an XML error.

Move the `</Request>` to the end:

```
<Request><Login>${ACCESS_KEY_ID}</Login><Password>${SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}</Password>
<ObjectLockConfiguration>
<ObjectLockEnabled>Enabled</ObjectLockEnabled>
<Rule><DefaultRetention>
<Mode>COMPLIANCE</Mode>
<Years>${RETYEARS}</Years>
</DefaultRetention></Rule>
</ObjectLockConfiguration></Request>
```

I used this online tool to find the error:
[XML Validator](https://codebeautify.org/xmlvalidator)

Comment: I fixed the error. Thanks for the link to the online XML tool. I still get the same kind of output returned though.

Comment: @Anders I updated my answer.   BTW, I do not know anything about the S3 API.  If you have a link to documentation using curl for S3, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your update. I am a beginner myself regarding the S3 API and I am sorry that I cannot provide a link to curl-S3-documentation. I have also been searching for it.

Comment: I will try to use the example "How to upload files on AWS S3 by using curl" ( https://www.gyanblog.com/aws/how-upload-aws-s3-curl/#curl-the-savior ), changing it slightly to set a retention period.

Comment: This is essentially what my script looks like now:

Comment: CONTENTTYPE="application/xml"
DATEVALUE=`date -R`
SIGNATURE_STRING="PUT\n\n${CONTENTTYPE}\n${DATEVALUE}"

SIGNATURE_HASH=`echo -en ${SIGNATURE_STRING} | openssl sha1 -hmac ${SECRET_ACCESS_KEY} -binary | base64`

Comment: curl -X PUT \
  -H "Host: ${BUCKET}.s3.amazonaws.com" \
  -H "Date: ${DATEVALUE}" \
  -H "Content-Type: ${CONTENTTYPE}" \
  -H "Authorization: AWS ${ACCESS_KEY_ID}:${SIGNATURE_HASH}" \
  -d "<ObjectLockConfiguration> \
          <ObjectLockEnabled>Enabled</ObjectLockEnabled> \
          <Rule> \
              <DefaultRetention> \
                  <Mode>COMPLIANCE</Mode> \
                  <Years>${RETYEARS}</Years> \
              </DefaultRetention> \
          </Rule> \
      </ObjectLockConfiguration>" \
  https://${BUCKET}.s3.amazonaws.com

Comment: Is something not working?

Comment: Yes, I still get error messages. But I think the reason probably is that we have some problems with our environment or configuration, here where I work.